# Quality of order

Tags: javascript, html

I do like to replace a HTML by an different HTML dynamically while the page displays. At the moment, I do `old.innerHTML = new.innerHTML` but this has the counterparts that:

1. a `<input>` having text editing will lose the text the user writes.
2. a `<input>` having text editing will lose the focus.
3. each CSS keyframe animations will restart, even if the node remains unchanged.

So I finally have to update every node step-by-step. That shouldnt be that hard if I divide the DOMTree into nodes and compare every nodes childs recursievly.

In Pseudocode I do this method recursive

1. Remove nodes from the current that not exists in new (working)
2. Add nodes to the current that exists only in new (working)
3. Order nodes in the current to match the order in new **(I stock here)**
4. Repeat for every child-node if exists.

To know what current-structure-child match the new-strucure-child the best, I use a `function elementEquality(a,b)` calculating a score.

After step 1 and step 2 I have nodes that:

- have the same [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType)
- have the same child-node-count
- do not have the same order

So in example starting with step 3 I have nodes like this:

```
 current  new        | elementEquality(a,b)-result
--------+------------+------
<!--->  | #text b    | 0
<div>   | <div>      | 50
#text b | <!--->     | 0
--------+------------+------
                       50 total quality points
```

I mean we see that the current-structure must swap the first and the 3rd element to match the order of new. The result would be like this:

```
--  solution is

 current  new        | elementEquality(a,b)-result
--------+------------+------
#text b | #text b    | 10
<div>   | <div>      | 50
<!--->  | <!--->     | 5
--------+------------+------
                       65 total quality points
```

We can do this with our mind but Id like to do this programatically.

My question is now, how to decide:

1. That the quality can be improoved.
2. What elements should be swapped.

One approach is to qualify every possible solution the brute-force way. But having 1 node makes 1 possible solution, having 2 nodes makes 2 possible solutions, 3 nodes makes 7 possible solutions (you see, it is exponential).

Comment: I find it kind of hard to understand **exactly** what you mean by `replace a HTML by an different HTML`. You want to change all nodes inside a container? And your problem is that, if you would just copy & paste it, the input fields would lose focus, the CSS animations start again, and so on...? Btw, is it possible that you have a example of code? It doesn't have to be working exactly as it should, but it would provide more details.

Comment: for me it sounds like an XY problem here http://xyproblem.info

Comment: you could try using [HTML templates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) which would make it better than what youre doing right now

Comment: @BugWhisperer Its not working in InternetExplorer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you're aiming to reinvent the wheel - morphDOM does exactly what you're trying to do:

> https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/morphdom

From the readme:

> Lightweight module for morphing an existing DOM node tree to match a target DOM node tree. It's fast and works with the real DOM—no virtual DOM needed!
>
> This module was created to solve the problem of updating the DOM in response to a UI component or page being rerendered. One way to update the DOM is to simply toss away the existing DOM tree and replace it with a new DOM tree (e.g., myContainer.innerHTML = newHTML). While replacing an existing DOM tree with an entirely new DOM tree will actually be very fast, it comes with a cost. The cost is that all of the internal state associated with the existing DOM nodes (scroll positions, input caret positions, CSS transition states, etc.) will be lost. Instead of replacing the existing DOM tree with a new DOM tree we want to transform the existing DOM tree to match the new DOM tree while minimizing the number of changes to the existing DOM tree. This is exactly what the morphdom module does! Give it an existing DOM node tree and a target DOM node tree and it will efficiently transform the existing DOM node tree to exactly match the target DOM node tree with the minimum amount of changes.
>
> morphdom does not rely on any virtual DOM abstractions. Because morphdom is using the real DOM, the DOM that the web browser is maintaining will always be the source of truth. Even if you have code that manually manipulates the DOM things will still work as expected. In addition, morphdom can be used with any templating language that produces an HTML string.
>
> The transformation is done in a single pass of both the original DOM tree and the target DOM tree and is designed to minimize changes to the DOM while still ensuring that the morphed DOM exactly matches the target DOM. In addition, the algorithm used by this module will automatically match up elements that have corresponding IDs and that are found in both the original and target DOM tree.